# Decorating a generic interface with Structuremap

Tags: c#, .net, structuremap

I have a generic interface, that takes in two generic types. I want to decorate all versions returned, but since I don't know the type when calling EnrichWith, it obviously doesn't compile. I've tried using the EnrichWith overload that passes in the context, thinking maybe I could grab the generic types passed in and call Activator.CreateInstance, but the context doesn't have any useful information on it when debugging and inspecting it.

Here's what I have so far. This is my generic interface:

```
public interface IServiceOperation<in TRequest, out TResponse> where TResponse : ServiceResult, new()
{
    TResponse PerformService(TRequest validatedRequest);
}
```

Here's a sample implementation:

```
public class SignUpService : IServiceOperation<SignUpRequest, SignUpResult>
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepo;

    public SignUpService(IUserRepository userRepo)
    {
        _userRepo = userRepo;
    }

    public SignUpResult PerformService(SignUpRequest validatedRequest)
    {
        var user = Mapper.Map<User>(validatedRequest);

        user.MarkAsLoggedIn();
        user.ChangePassword(validatedRequest.UnhashedPassword);

        using(var transaction = _userRepo.BeginTransaction())
        {
            _userRepo.Save(user);
            transaction.Commit();
        }

        return new SignUpResult();
    }
}
```

Here is my decorator, that takes in another service as well:

```
public class ValidateServiceDecorator<TRequest, TResponse> : IServiceOperation<TRequest, TResponse> where TResponse : ServiceResult, new()
{
    private readonly IServiceOperation<TRequest, TResponse> _serviceOperation;
    private readonly IValidationService _validationService;

    public ValidateServiceDecorator(IServiceOperation<TRequest, TResponse> serviceOperation,
        IValidationService validationService)
    {
        _serviceOperation = serviceOperation;
        _validationService = validationService;
    }

    public TResponse PerformService(TRequest request)
    {
        var response = new TResponse();
        var validationResult = _validationService.Validate(request);

        if (!validationResult.IsValid)
        {
            response.ValidationErrors = validationResult.ValidationErrors;
            return response;
        }

        return _serviceOperation.PerformService(request);
    }
```

Lastly, here is how far I've gotten on my container. This obviously doesn't compile, but the EnrichWith line shows what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public class StructureMapServiceScanner : Registry
{
    public StructureMapServiceScanner()
    {
        Scan(scanner =>
                {
                    scanner.AssemblyContainingType(typeof (IServiceOperation<,>));
                    scanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof (IServiceOperation<,>));
                });

        For(typeof (IServiceOperation<,>))
        .EnrichWith((ioc, original) => new ValidateServiceDecorator(original, ioc.GetInstance<IValidationService>()));
    }
}
```

And just because this question needed a little more code, here's my test that I'm trying to get to pass:

```
[TestClass]
public class StructureMapServiceScannerSpecs
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        ObjectFactory.Configure(cfg =>
                                    {
                                        cfg.AddRegistry<StructureMapServiceScanner>();
                                        cfg.For<IUserRepository>().Use(new Mock<IUserRepository>().Object);
                                        cfg.For<IValidationService>().Use(new Mock<IValidationService>().Object);
                                    });

        var service = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IServiceOperation<SignUpRequest, SignUpResult>>();

        service.ShouldNotBeNull();
        service.ShouldBeType<ValidateServiceDecorator<SignUpRequest, SignUpResult>>();
    }
}
```

I feel like this is something that should be simple, and I'm really missing something with how to use StructureMap. I could create type-specific versions for all combinations of Request and Response types, but obviously that's not desirable. So what am I missing?

Comment: Was able to figure it out, using a RegistrationConvention to enrich each closed type of the interface directly. I'd post what I did, but I can't for another few hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was able to figure it out, eventually. I created a RegistrationConvention:

```
public class ServiceRegistrationConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        var interfacesImplemented = type.GetInterfaces();

        foreach (var interfaceImplemented in interfacesImplemented)
        {
            if (interfaceImplemented.IsGenericType && interfaceImplemented.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IServiceOperation<,>))
            {
                var genericParameters = interfaceImplemented.GetGenericArguments();
                var closedValidatorType = typeof(ValidateServiceDecorator<,>).MakeGenericType(genericParameters);

                registry.For(interfaceImplemented)
                    .EnrichWith((context, original) => Activator.CreateInstance(closedValidatorType, original,
                                                                                context.GetInstance<IValidationService>()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that still leverages StructureMap's IoC capabilities, allowing additional services to be injected easily into your decorator.  It's not perfect since it assumes you are using the primary container and not a child container, but it will probably work for most scenarios.

```
public class ServiceRegistrationConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        var handlerInterfaces = (from t in type.GetInterfaces()
                                 where t.IsGenericType &&
                                       t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (IHandle<,>)
                                 select t);

        foreach (var handler in handlerInterfaces)
        {
            var decoratorType = typeof (ValidationDecorator<,>).MakeGenericType(handler.GetGenericArguments());

            registry.For(handler)
                .EnrichWith((ctx, orig) => ObjectFactory.With(handler, orig).GetInstance(decoratorType));
        }
    }
}
```

Ideally, StructureMap's IContext should expose the With method just like IContainer does.  Without that, there's not really a great solution to this problem.