# Implementing the strategy pattern with generics and StructureMap

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, structuremap

I am trying to implement the strategy pattern in my repository layer using SM and generics. For that I have an interface, IPocoRepository, which has a concrete implementation using Entity Framework. This I have managed to wire up in my Bootstrapper-file:

```
For(typeof(IPocoRepository<>)).Use(typeof(EntityFrameworkRepository<>));
```

The problem appears when I try to implement caching for this interface. In my cached class I want an instance of the base repository class, so that I can keep my design DRY. Let me outline how these three files look:

```
public interface IPocoRepository<T>
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    ...


public class EntityFrameworkRepository<T> : IPocoRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        ...

public class CachedRepository<T> : IPocoRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private IPocoRepository<T> _pocoRepository;

    public CachedRepository(IPocoRepository<T> pr)
    {
        _pocoRepository = pr;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        var all = (IQueryable<T>)CacheProvider.Get(_cacheKey);
        if (!CacheProvider.IsSet(_cacheKey))
        {
            all = _pocoRepository.GetAll();
            ...
```

Edit: I want StructureMap to return CachedRepository when IPocoRepository is requested, *except when requested for in CachedRepository* - then I want it to return EntityFrameworkRepository.

I know this is simple when dealing with non-generic classes:

```
For<ICountyRepository>().Use<CachedCountyRepository>()
.Ctor<ICountyRepository>().Is<CountyRepository>();
```

I tried searching the documentation for how to do this, but couldn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So what's the actual problem? It looks to me as if you're trying to replicate what frameworks like Castle Windsor do.

Comment: I have updated the question; hopefully making it more clear what I am asking. I am hoping to stick with StructureMap

Comment: That's what a dependency injection framework do, have a look at http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx - It'll probably make a lot of sense. :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954988/decorating-a-generic-interface-with-structuremap

Comment: This article might help: http://robtechdiff.blogspot.nl/2011/11/decorating-generic-interface-with.html

Comment: How hooked are you to StructureMap?

Comment: I can replace Structuremap without too much effort, but I do not want to do that, unless I find that this can not be solved! Thanks for the links; there is definitely a similiar problem described in the blog post. I hope I can use some of it to solve my problem.

Comment: Altough similiar, the problem outlined in the blog/other SO post is not the same one I am having. I will update my post with additional information about my implementation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this isn't too hard. You can use a type interceptor. Given you have the following classes:

```
public interface IRepository<T>{}

public class Repository<T>:IRepository<T>{}

public class RepositoryCache<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    private readonly IRepository<T> _internalRepo;

    public RepositoryCache(IRepository<T> internalRepo)
    {
        _internalRepo = internalRepo;
    }

    public IRepository<T> InternalRepo
    {
        get { return _internalRepo; }
    }
}
```

You will then need to create a type interceptor. You can use the configurable "MatchedTypeInterceptor" provided by StructureMap for this. The interceptor will need to look for your repositories and then figure out what the generic type parameters are. Once it has the type parameters it can declare the type of cache it needs and initialize it. As part of the initialization, it will take the original repository in it's constructor. Then the interceptor will return the completed cache to whatever requested it from the ioc context. Here is the complete sequence inside a test.

This can be moved out into your registry, I just left it all together as an minimal example.

```
    [Test]
    public void doTest()
    {
        MatchedTypeInterceptor interceptor = new MatchedTypeInterceptor(
             x => x.FindFirstInterfaceThatCloses(typeof (IRepository<>)) != null);

        interceptor.InterceptWith(original =>
        {
            Type closedType = original.GetType()
                 .FindFirstInterfaceThatCloses(typeof(IRepository<>));

            var genericParameters = closedType.GetGenericArguments();

            var closedCacheType = typeof(RepositoryCache<>)
                 .MakeGenericType(genericParameters);

            return Activator.CreateInstance(closedCacheType, new[] {original});
        });

        ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
        {
            x.For(typeof (IRepository<>)).Use(typeof (Repository<>));
            x.RegisterInterceptor(interceptor);
        });

        var test = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IRepository<int>>();

        Assert.That(test is RepositoryCache<int>);
    }
```

Comment: Well done! I did a test on the _internalRepo field in your code, and it is indeed an instance of Repository<T> - just what I wanted! Thanks a lot!:)